# Optimal way to read a file concurrently

Tags: go, concurrency

So I have a file like this:

```
NAME : a280
COMMENT : drilling problem (Ludwig)
TYPE : TSP
DIMENSION: 280
EDGE_WEIGHT_TYPE : EUC_2D
NODE_COORD_SECTION
  1 288 149
  2 288 129
  3 270 133
  4 256 141
  5 256 157
  6 246 157
  7 236 169
  8 228 169
  9 228 161
 10 220 169
 11 212 169
 12 204 169
 13 196 169
 14 188 169
 15 196 161
```

and so on...

The numbers are the cords for cities to solve TSP. I am trying to write this in Golang. Now the instances can be like 200 cities, or even 40.000 cities. I want to get the best possible solution, so I thought I should process this file concurrently. I've got following code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "regexp"
    "strings"
)

func getCords(queue chan string) {
    cords := regexp.MustCompile(`\s*\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+`)
    for line := range queue {
        if cords.MatchString(line) {
            fmt.Println(line)
        }
    }
}

func readFile(fileName string) {
    cords := make(chan string)
    file := strings.NewReader(fileName)
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            cords <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(cords)
    }()
}

// Menu - main program menu
func Menu() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Println("==================    Projektowanie efektywnych algorytmów    ==================")
    fmt.Println("==================    Zadanie nr 1 - Algorytm xyz             ==================")
    // Wczytywanie pliku z danymi
    // Format: Lp. X Y
    fmt.Printf("\nPodaj nazwę pliku: ")
    fileName, err := reader.ReadString('\n')
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    readFile(fileName)
}

func main() {
    Menu()
}
```

In function `getCords` I need to useregex, cuz the files tend to have information part at the beginning.

The problem starts in `readFile()`. I launch a goroutine, which scans the file line by line and gets all the lines to the channel. Of course the execution just launches it and goes futher. Now the problem is, after the `go func()` call, I would have to try read from the channel. The solutions I found on SO, and on the internet were as following:

```
func readFile(fileName string) {
    cords := make(chan string)
    file := strings.NewReader(fileName)
    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            cords <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(cords)
    }()
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        go getCords(cords)
    }
}
```

So te first execution of getCords would probably even do nothing, because the goroutine would not manage to get the line to the channel that fast. Next iterations would probably do the job, but the problem is I have to write some number, like `100` in this example, and it can be too high, so the channel will get closed in like 10 iterations and after that it's just a waste of time or it can be too low, and then I would just not get all the results.

How do you solve problems like this, guys? Is there optimal way, or do I have to stick with some `waitGroups`?

Comment: start by writing a sequential version that works, then, find out the slowest parts of the program using profiling, finally starts to add concurrency to the program, in the relevant places. besides, https://github.com/AkshanshChahal/TSP-Golang

Comment: You are not opening any files anywhere in your code. `file := strings.NewReader(fileName)` does not open and load data from `fileName`. `os.Open` does that: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Open.

Answer (score 1):

I think yes, it would be good to use `sync.WaitGroup` to ensure all goroutines have finished their work. One possible solution:

```
func getCords(queue Chas string, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
     defer wg.Done()
     // your code 
 }

func readFile(fileName string) {
    cords := make(chan string)
    file := strings.NewReader(fileName)

    go func() {
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
        for scanner.Scan() {
            cords <- scanner.Text()
        }
        close(cords)
    }()

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go getCords(cords, wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Comment: But one goroutine does all the reading to the channel. So this goroutine gets started, and the execution goes further. Then where should I call `go getCords()`

Comment: I've updated the code. It's not a problem - because write to `cords <- scanner.Text()` will be blocked. Because there's nobody to read from the channel until `getCoords` goroutines are started. Also you can swap these 2 blocks: start consumers `getCoords` before and later start producer - file reader.

Comment: Right, forgot sending blocks goroutine until someone reads from the channel. Don't I have to pass `wg` by pointer? And why do you do the for loop for `100` iterations, when we don't know how many lines will it read?

Comment: And by they way, your code doesn't work in two ways. First, getCords doesn't accept `sync.WaitGroup` passed by value, and second when I change it, the program execution ends with no result (like when I add `fmt.Println` to getCords). F.e it just printed the name of the file

Comment: Of course, `wg` should be passed by the ponter. There's also should be `Open` as a commenter above stated. Unfortunately I'll check it later when get to my laptop, not phone.